# How can I combine two render layers?

Tags: compositing-nodes, node-editor, render-layers

I would like to know which nodes can I combine this two render layers  width?

[image: This is my question]

I've made this with alpha over node and transparent rendering. I want such an image but I don't want to lose the background (Sky texture).

[image: I want this.]

Thanks for helping! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setup using the alphaover node and transparent rendering is a good idea, try going back to that and make the following changes: First go to your Blur renderlayer (in the renderlayer panel) and turn on the Environment pass,

[image: Layers]

then go to the compositor and add a second alphaover node. Plug the output of the first alphaover node into the bottom input of the second, then plug the Environment pass from the renderlayer into the other image input and pipe the alphaover output to the composite node. 
[image: Nodes]

Comment: Those screenshots would help future viewers a lot . . .

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Thanks for reminding me, Screenshots added :)

Comment: Awesome! Really helps to have some examples like that.

Comment: Not sure if this works in your case, but in my case I used a mix node that I have set to "Add".