# How do I combine three rendered animated layers?

Tags: rendering, animation, compositing-nodes, render-layers, layers

[image: 1st layer]

[image: 2nd layer]

[image: 3rd layer]

I animated these 3 layers and than tried combining but couldn't do it.
I know how to combine rendered images from different layers in compositor but I'm trying out animation.
Please help.!!!

Comment: show what you tried, the setup that didn't work, to spot what was wrong or what to change...

Comment: I clicked on animation besides the render button... After that I don't know how to combine all three animated layers to make a single animation out of them..!!

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you enable transparency for the background (so that all of the layers have an alpha channel.

[image]

Then combine the layers in the compositor using **Alpha Over**

[image]

[image]

For a more detailed explanation Read:
[My objects are semi-transparent, and not one behind the other in the compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49049/my-objects-are-semi-transparent-and-not-one-behind-the-other-in-the-compositor/49137#49137)
and [Can someone explain the layer system?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/can-someone-explain-the-layer-system)

Comment: what if i want to make an animation, how do i combine three animated layers and than save it?

Comment: @DeepPatel please ask new questions using the big blue **Ask Question** link at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can  <kbd>shift</kbd> + Left Click  on the Layers at the bottom panel to select which to render.

If you need more advanced control on how to combine them you can [composite](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21440/how-can-i-combine-two-render-layers) them together using render layers.

Comment: More info on layers: [Can someone explain the layer system?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33897/can-someone-explain-the-layer-system)